# Overlap plots in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I currently have a contour plot, just like this one here

[image]

http://www.originlab.com/www/helponline/Origin/en/mergedProjects/Tutorial/images/Contour_Plot_with_Major_and_Minor_Levels_Filled_by_Using_Color_Palette/Graph_Gallery_Contour_Plot_Palette_16.png,

now I want to add some simple plots of functions in the length width plane, like f(width) = width^n and so on, but I don't know how to overlap these two plots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you want to retain the current graph when adding new graphs: use `hold on`. See http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/hold.html.